# Best method of Instantiating an XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest

What is the best method for creating an [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object?

It should work in all capable browsers.

Comment: As an additional info, this topic will also be useful: [JavaScript: Which should I use, Microsoft.XMLHTTP or Msxml2.XMLHTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1919582/814702)

Answer (score 11):

For a library-less solution, you can emulate Prototype's use of `Try.these` fairly easily:

```
function newAjax() {
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest();                    } catch(){}
    try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0'); } catch(){}
    try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0'); } catch(){}
    try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');     } catch(){}
    try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');  } catch(){}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Clean and spartan. Might want to "remember" the located version so you don't have to hit 1-4 exceptions every time.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a useful link and some code (should cover all bases)

http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx

```
        var request = null;

        function InitAJAX()
        {
            var objxml = null;
            var ProgID = ["Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];            

            try
            {
                objxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(e)
            {                
                for (var i = 0; i < ProgID.length; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        objxml = new ActiveXObject(ProgID[i]);
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {                        
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            return objxml;            
        }

        request = InitAJAX();
```

Comment: @Bishiboosh - It works fine in Firefox - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 8):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (or a similar JavaScript library).  It takes care of the cross-browser compatibility issues of things like making Ajax calls.

[For example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ajaxjquery.html), using the [jQuery Ajax call](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'document.xml',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(){
        alert('Error loading XML document');
    },
    success: function(xml){
        // do something with xml
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest following [Sergey's advise](https://web.archive.org/web/20170503184005/http://code.google.com/p/xmlhttprequest/) or writing a small, less sophisticated patch for IE yourself:

```
if(typeof window.XMLHttpRequest === 'undefined' &&
    typeof window.ActiveXObject === 'function') {
    window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
        try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0'); } catch(e) {}
        try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0'); } catch(e) {}
        return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    };
}
```

Then you can do

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
```

even in IE.

**edit 2011-02-18:** see [this blogpost](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314160956/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx) for the rationale behind the new choice of MSXML versions...

Comment: the link is great, that fix the object

Answer (score 3):

Using just about any JavaScript [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) library is preferable to writing your own Ajax framework -- unless that's the point.  You might want to check out the jQuery or [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework) or [MooTools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools) or [Dojo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) or [insert name here] framework to see how they do it if you insist on writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use, it works fine for me:

```
    function request()
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }
            catch( e )
            {
                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            }
        }
        catch(e) 
        {
            return new XMLHttpRequest()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [XMLHttpRequest.js - Standard-compliant cross-browser XMLHttpRequest object implementation](http://code.google.com/p/xmlhttprequest/) and work with the object in a [standard (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) way

Answer (score 0):

I go with Cletus's suggestion of jQuery and also check out the [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plug-in, very powerful and simple to use to quickly convert your forms to work via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

function CreateXmlHttpObj() {

```
try {
    XmlHttpObj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e) {
    try {
        XmlHttpObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (oc) {
        XmlHttpObj = null;
    }
}
// if unable to create using IE specific code then try creating for Mozilla (FireFox) 
if (!XmlHttpObj && typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
    XmlHttpObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

}