# Define Javascript Variable With Contents of URL

Tags: javascript, url, httprequest

I have found a geocoder website that will give me some data that I need as a variable in my javascript code: http://geocoder.us/service/csv/geocode?zip=95472. the website returns only the content: 38.393314, -122.83666, Sebastopol, CA, 95472. I need pull this information from the website and put it into a string.

abc = "38.393314, -122.83666, Sebastopol, CA, 95472"

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: exact duplicate of [Reading external plain text content into string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312561/reading-external-plain-text-content-into-string)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX):

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Create an AJAX object
req.open('GET','http://geocoder.us/service/csv/geocode?zip=95472',true); //Location and method
req.send(); //Send
req.onreadystatechange = function() { //When it's ready
    if (this.readyState === 4) { //... which is code 4
        console.log(this.responseText); //Then you have the responseText
    }
}
```

This only works when the request is from the same domain, tho (for security purposes). If you want it to work on any domain, you'll have to use a proxy.

Comment: This might not work because of cross-domain restrictions

Answer (score 1):

You should use Javascript to make an ajax request to that URL and it will return the information you want in a format you specify, usually JSON. Depending on what Javascript libraries you are/aren't using, there's different ways you could do that -- probably the most common would be to use jQuery to make your request. Here's info on that API:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks for the tip! I'll add relevant info.