# JavaScript: Which should I use, Microsoft.XMLHTTP or Msxml2.XMLHTTP?

Tags: javascript, ajax

There are two progid's.  I've seen both used.

Anyone have any insight as to when I should use one, versus the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hai Cheeso,

Have a look at these
http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/559991-msxml-xmlhttp-vs-microsoft-xmlhttp

http://forums.asp.net/p/1000060/1622845.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You should definitely not use Microsoft.XmlHttp.

From the **Microsoft XML Team blog**: [Using the right version of MSXML in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx): <sup>*([archive](https://archive.vn/wip/tCKkz))*</sup>

> **MSXML2 vs. Microsoft namespace** – I’ve also seen a lot of code that
> instantiates the "`Microsoft.XMLHTTP`"
> ActiveX object rather than the
> `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0` or
> `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0` if you’re using
> 6.0.  The “Microsoft” namespace is actually older and is only implemented
> in MSXML3 for legacy support.  It’s
> unfortunate we used the “better” name
> on the older version, but stick to the
> “msxml2” namespace when instantiating
> objects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly the answer you want, but that, if you are developping an Ajax application, I'd say you shouldn't use either of those : instead, you should use a Javascript Framework that will deal with browser compatibility, and not re-fight that battle.

For instance (there are many more) :

- [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)

And, as a sidenote, they'll get you plenty of other useful stuff ;-)

Comment: Seconded. There is no need to meddle with browser specific implementations here, except maybe for some *really* specific stuff that can't be done cross browser. Use a framework and be done with it.

Comment: Can I download binary blobs using the ajax capability in jQuery?  Any of the above?

Comment: Hmm.. not so sure, Vanilla js is the best performing approach.

Answer (score 0):

This code takes care of both IE and firefox.

```
try {
  XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (exception1) {
  try {
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (exception2) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
  }
}

if (!XMLHttpRequestObject && window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```