# Why should I test for MSXML2.XmlHttp and Microsoft.XmlHttp version-independent ProgIDs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, activexobject

I have read [the MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx) about it.
And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919582/javascript-which-should-i-use-microsoft-xmlhttp-or-msxml2-xmlhttp) doesn't help me much either.
As far as I can tell checking Microsoft.XmlHttp is enough.

1. Can you confirm [this
   bug](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/987)? (POST enforcing)
2. Is there a solid source which explains the non-UTF charset issue Iv been reading about? Is it better handled by MSXML2.XmlHttp?
3. **Are there any earlier version(s) of IE which require(s) `Microsoft.XmlHttp`?**

Answer (score 1):

You should check MSXML2.XmlHttp, not Microsoft.XmlHttp, as stated [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx)

They are exactly the same except maybe for somone with IE4 or IE5, but do you really want to support this? The post is from the guys building MSXML, you can't find a more reliable source.

As for the jquery bug, nobody can confirm it exactly because XMLHTTP issues are not related to IE, but rather to the version of the underlying XMLHTTP object. Since MSXML3 is serviced regularly by Microsoft, the XMLHTTP version IE is relying on, can change anytime.

Comment: The jquery ticket is irrelevant - what's interesting is the bug on the underlying difference between MSXML2.XmlHttp and Microsoft.XmlHttp concerning POST versus GET. You didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: I don't think you will ever find anything more relevant than the link I posted, because it's from the guys who write and support MSXML. At the end, it basically says that you should check the "MSXML2" namespace, not the "Microsoft" one , and don't bother about anything else.